# How to resolve waitForTransform timeout exception regardless of Duration value in ROS Kinetic (python)?

Tags: rospy, transform-listener, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have gone through similar questions on this website, but none have helped resolve the problem for me.

`listener.waitForTransform("world", "camera_link", rospy.Time(0), rospy.Duration(4.0))`

- My TF tree is well defined and shows the connection between the two frames (world and a camera frame). It's World -> Link 1 -> Link 2 -> Camera Link I check this based on rqt-graph.
- If I replace "world" above with "Link 2" I don't get the timeout exception, which is interesting.
- As I mentioned, changing Duration doesn't help.
- The `use_sim_time` parameter is also defined and set to True.

Not sure how to proceed on this at all.

Something which might be important -

I am working through VMWare. Due to some issue with vmware tools, I had to run the `sudo apt-get autoremove` command. Which, unfortunately, ended up removing some of the ROS packages. So I am thinking that might be related to this problem, but I can't be sure. I have tried reinstalling the tf, tf2, geometry packages till now becacuse some posts suggested it to be a problem related to those. Didn't help.

Any idea on how to debug/solve this? I can provide more information if required.

***Update:***

Just after posting this, I tried to run `tf_echo` for those two. And I get this error -

`Exception thrown:Could not find a connection between 'camera_link' and 'world' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.`

Which is weird and interesting because this seems to contradict the first point I have above.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264945/how-to-resolve-waitfortransform-timeout-exception-regardless-of-duration-value-in-ros-kinetic-(python)?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2017-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it turns out, it's a known issue and it seems the fix hasn't been merged properly yet to a specific version. The main clue here was the `tf view_frames` didn't show the `world` frame but `rqt` did. That caused a problem since the issue is related to `tf_static` as pointed by the issues/pull request below.

https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/136

https://github.com/ros/geometry/pull/134

The issue above - 136, mentions a workaround. To set the `use_tf_static` parameter to `false` for the `robot_state_publisher`.

It's as simple as

```
 <arg name="use_tf_static" default="false"/> 
 <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" >
          <param name="use_tf_static" value="$(arg use_tf_static)"/>
 </node>
```

For now, this seems to fix the problem. I will work with this and see if there's any issues, but for now I think this answers my original question.

---

Originally posted by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) with karma: 237 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0